# Converting MySQL code with date functions to MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Working with one of my applications, I am adding two databases support to my project, but I am very limited in my knowledge with MSSQL. My MySQL code is like below

```
SELECT count(ip_address) AS failed_login_attempt 
FROM failed_login 
WHERE ip_address = '$ip' 
  AND date BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND NOW()
```

and I am trying to do same kind of functionality with MSSQL:

```
SELECT count(ip_address) AS failed_login_attempt 
FROM failed_login 
WHERE ip_address = '$ip' 
  AND date between [tHIS pIECE OF cODE I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO FIx ]
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has several ways of returning the current date, for example `getdate()`. To subtract one day from the current datetime use the `dateadd` function. So this:

`BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND NOW()`

should be equivalent to

`BETWEEN dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) and getdate()`

Comment: This is the correct answer.  For brevity, you can also write `between getdate() - 1 and getdate()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Good point! I actually wasn't aware that MSSQL allowed arithmetic on datetime in this way - I've always relied on the functions.